# nill error when trying to concatenate a string

Tags: swift

I followed a tutorial and did everything correct. I can print out the age in the console just when I try to set the labels text I get a nil error.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet var inputField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var outputLbl: UILabel!

    @IBAction func enterBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        if(inputField != nil){

           var age = inputField.text.toInt()
           println(age)

           var catYears = age! * 7
           println(catYears)
           outputLbl.text = "Your cat is \(catYears)  old"
        }
        else {            
           outputLbl.text = "Please enter a age"
        }
    }    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I read the documentation and I'm concatenating the string correctly. However like I said, when I take the follow statement out:

```
outputLbl.text = "Your cat is \(catYears)  old"
```

the program run fine.

Comment: The Text Field will never be nil once the view has loaded, you might want to test to see if there is any content in the input field. `if inputField.text != "" {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this made a difference but I deleted the label and recreated it and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend refactoring this to check whether the entered text is able to be converted into an int. You should not check whether the `textField != nil` since is will not be nil if the storyboard loaded properly.

Consider this change:

```
@IBAction func enterBtn(sender: UIButton) {

    if let age = inputField.text.toInt() {
        println(age)

        var catYears = age * 7
        println(catYears)
        outputLbl.text = "Your cat is \(catYears) old"
    } else {
        outputLbl.text = "Please enter a valid age"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and got the following same error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Just to clarify, it only happens when you push the enter button? and it crashes with an EXE_BAD_ACCESS? which line is the crash pointing to?

Comment: Might be that one of your outlets has become disconnected?